# Querying DocumentDb for Inner results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a document with this structure:

```
  [{
  "id": "test",
  "StudentRules": [
    {
      "id": "d8b730905",
      "name": "Test",
      "ruletype": "Allow",
      "startdate": "5/7/2015 10:05:15 AM"
    }
   ]
```

I need to write a query that will give me all the "StudentRules" for a given id "test".

I wrote this:

```
select * from json j where j.id = "test"
```

This returns the structure as the example above.
I am expecting this:

```
       [
        {
          "id": "d8b730905",
          "name": "Test",
          "ruletype": "Allow",
          "startdate": "5/7/2015 10:05:15 AM"
        }
       ]
```

The idea is to have all the rules in a list which will be shown in an MVC application.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `JOIN` keyword to form cross products with nested array elements:

```
SELECT Rule.id, Rule.name, Rule.ruletype, Rule.startdate 
FROM root 
JOIN Rule IN root.StudentRules 
WHERE root.id = "test"
```

You may find looking at the sample queries on [DocumentDB's query playground](http://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo) useful.